# getting error while iterating with page Break in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am working for an application where I need to copy-paste a range from another sheet. I need to know if the copied range fits in the available space. Everything works except I get a Run-time error '9' after a certain iteration.

here is my code

```
Function checkBlockFits(buildingRg As Range, pasteRg As Range) As Boolean
        checkBlockFits = True
        
        Dim sRow As Long: sRow = pasteRg.row
        Dim eRow As Long: eRow = sRow + 10000
        
        'find pageBreak Row
        Dim pb As HPageBreak, rw As Long
        pbCount = shPdf.HPageBreaks.count
        
        For Each pb In shPdf.HPageBreaks
                rw = pb.Location.row
                If rw > sRow And rw < eRow Then Exit For
        Next pb
        
        'find available Height
        Dim aHeight As Double: aHeight = getRowHeight(Range(Cells(sRow, 1), Cells(rw, 1)))
        
        'find required Height
        Dim rHeight As Double: rHeight = getRowHeight(buildingRg)
        
        If aHeight < rHeight Then checkBlockFits = False

End Function
```

I checked that the pbCount has a value of 159 just before the error occurs in the beginning of the for loop. This is very strange because I used this function over and over again inside a loop and it throws an error only at a particular point (it doesn't want to go inside the for loop: "For Each pb In shPdf.HPageBreaks").
For all the iteration before this, it is working and for every instance the Pbcount=159 [I have 159 pages in the excel page-break view)

can anyone help?

[image showing pb count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iigDX.png)[actual error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwBgf.jpg)

Comment: Are `pbCount` and `shPdf` globals and is `pasteRg` a range on `shPdf` ? `Range(Cells(sRow, 1)` and `Cells(rw, 1)` are not qualified with a sheet ref which can cause problems.

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes, there are all globals. Basically I have this function inside a loop. They all work perfectly fine but throws an error at some point of iteration.

Comment: It's weird. Pls try `pbCount = shPdf.HPageBreaks.Count
    For i = 1 To pbCount
        Set pb = shPdf.HPageBreaks(i)
        <Your code>
    Next`